# Can't instantiate object in javascript (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi can someone tell me why I can't instantiate the following class/object?

```
function Arbitrage(odds1, odds2, investment)
{
    this.investment = investment;
    this.odds1 = odds1;
    this.odds2 = odds2;

    this.arbPercent = function() {
        return 1.0/this.odds1 + 1.0/this.odds2;
    };

    this.profit = function() {
        return this.investment / this.arbPercent() - this.investment;
    };

    this.individualBets = function() {
        return    {
                odds1bet : this.investment/this.odds1/this.arbPercent(),
                odds2bet : this.investment/this.odds2/this.arbPercent()    
            };
    };
};

module.exports = Arbitrage;
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
var utility = require('../businesslogic/utility');
...
router.post('/calculate', function(req, res)
    {
        var arbit = new utility.Arbitrage(req.body.odds1, req.body.odds2, req.body.investment);
        res.json({
            arbPercentage : arbit.arbPercent(),
            profit : arbit.Profit(),
            indvBets : arbit.individualBets()
        });
    });
```

The first line, `var arbit = new utility.Arbitrage(...)` is throwing the error. 
It says `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

I've checked that `utility` isn't null or anything like that. Also all the constructor arguments are ok.

I'm not very familiar with javascript, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the name of the file where you have defined ``Arbitrage``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're exporting your `Arbitrage` class directly, so after you're requiring it

```
var utility = require('../businesslogic/utility');
```

`utility` is actually your `Arbitrage` class, meaning that `typeof utility === 'function'`.

I can see two ways of fixing it.

**1.** Change the way you're requiring your `Arbitrage` class:

```
var Arbitrage = require('../businesslogic/utility');
// ...
var arbit = new Arbitrage(...);
```

**2.** Or change the way you're exporting it:

```
exports.Arbitrage = Arbitrage;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. If I wanted to export utility...as a namespace...is that possible? Would I have to keep adding each new function I add in there to exports.[name] individually?

Comment: @shek you could prefix each new function definition with `exports.[name] = ` instead of exporting all your functions at the end of your module, e.g. `exports.Arbitrage = function Arbitrage(...) {...`.

Comment: You can import multiple files in your utility file and export them a separate objects.
var AnotherUtility = require('./AnotherUtility.js');
exports.AnotherUtility = AnotherUtility

Answer (score -1):

it's because of the way you exported it

you should use :

```
module.exports.Arbitrage = Arbitrage;
```

And then you can instanciate like this :

```
var Arbitrage = require('../businesslogic/utility');
var varbitrage = new Arbitrage();
```

Comment: It he'll do both things he'll get `object is not a function` error.